# multiple cron.yaml on appengine within same project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have multiple apps with cron.yaml deploying on google appengine within same project id. But when one deploys, its over writing cron defs from other app. Both apps has its own target defined but deployment using maven is over writing cron defs. I couldn't find much info. online or google docs. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: You mean modules/services, not apps, right? If not - you can't use the same app ID for multiple apps - they'll just overwrite each-other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron is configured **per project**, not module. You have to merge all of this files into one, and deploy just this file.

To update just cron file, Maven have a special task:

```
mvn appengine:update_cron
```

It will upload `cron.yaml` for current project